# Importing base image twice in the same dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Can I use aliases for base image? For e.g. is this valid in dockerfile?

```
FROM some_image AS builder
```

I can see the use of this like...

https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator/blob/master/Dockerfile

But I will like to know if this is officially supported syntax.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from has the official syntax, and the `FROM ... AS` version is pretty common these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its officially supported by `docker` and termed as multistage builder. It will help to reduce the `docker` image size considerably.